# How do you open the door to Mr. Burke's office without being detected?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I am currently doing a Factory 0 playthrough of "The Missing Link" and I need to get into Mr. Burke's Office.

Now when I get there, there is a camera pointing at the door and one guard.

I am unable to take out the guard or hacking the door without getting spotted by the camera.

I know that there is a ventshaft inside the office. But to get into it, you need to hack the next door with security rating 3 or a hatch one floor down which has the same rating, so both are not possible.

How do I get inside or where can I disable the camera?

Comment: An EMP can disable the camera for a short period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Code 5768 on the maintainance Hatch a floor down.

Answer (score 5):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7H8DOqIiBA) demonstrates how to get into Mr. Burk's office without being detected. The camera itself doesn't always point at the door and rotates, giving you a window of opportunity where you can sneak up to the door, stand behind the guard and hack the door.

The window of opportunity is about 25 seconds and during this time you will need to move into position without alerting the guard, hack the door, open the door and then lose the alert status you gain from opening the door (which you can do by hiding out of line of sight inside Mr Burke's office).

Being a game of choice there is no 'right' answer and it's very much down to your play-style and character build.

Comment: EMP is not possible, Factory0 walkthrough.

Comment: @user28015 amended answer accordingly